# Connection to port 22 is not accessible with my network

Tags: networking, ssh

I'm trying to connect to ssh port 22. But I'm getting this error

```
Network is unreachable
```

I was trying to clone a repo from gitlab. But I'm not getting any response. This occurs only when I use a specific network connection. Given below is the result that I got while trying to clone:

```
Cloning into 'gitlab-ci-poc'...
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

After I changed the network to another provider, it was working.

The same issue occurred when I tried to connect an EC2 machine using SSH. At that time also, I needed to change my network. No idea what is the issue. I don't think it is an issue with my machine, but not sure.

How can I identify the issue? Or is this a network provider's issue. Not sure. How can I troubleshoot???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For GitLab there's an alternative to using port 22, check out this article: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/

In general, some ISP block traffic on specific ports, same thing that happens in public networks like in hotels. Given your description it seems to be one specific provider. As a suggestion - just look up if there's publicly available information about said provider and ports or alternatively contact them and simply ask.

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue with the network provider. Sometimes, they blocked perticular ports for some reasons.

- In this problem, you can use git over `https` instead of `ssh`.